# The file is located inside the folder but I am having a WinError 3 cannot find file

Tags: python

I am attempting to learn python, and I have coded this code for a random madlib generator. But when I go to run the program, it says that it cannot find the path specified despite the folder existing, and holding the .json files.
I am on Windows 10.
Why is this error occuring?
Is it because ./ is a Linux command?
Thank you for your help and advice.

I am posting my code here:

```
import random
import json
import os


class CreateaMadLib:
    Path = "./MadLibGen"
    def __init__(self, Word_Desc, Temp):
        self.Temp = Temp
        self.Word_Desc = Word_Desc
        self.UserInput = []
        self.Story = None
        
        
    @classmethod
    def Get__From__Json(cls, Name, Path=None):
        if not Path:
            Path = cls.path
        fpath = os.path.join(Path, Name)
        with open(fpath, "r") as F:
            Data = json.load(F)
            Create_a_MadLib = cls(**Data)
        return Create_a_MadLib      

    def Get__The__Words__From__TheUser(self):
        print("Please enter the words that you want: ")
        for desc in self.Word_Desc:
            UI = input(desc + " ")
            self.UserInput.append(UI)
        return self.UserInput


    def Build__A__Story(self, Word):
        self.Story = self.Temp.format(*self.UserInput)
        return self.Story
        
    def Display_A_MadLib_Story(self):
        print(Story)
    
    def Choose_A_MadLib_Temp():
        print("Please choose the Mad Lib that you want from the list:")
        MadLibGen = os.listdir(CreateaMadLib.path)
        Temp = input(str(MadLibGen) + " ")
        return Temp
        
        Temp_Name = Choose_A_MadLib_Temp()
        #Temp_Name = "ArcadeMadLib.json"
        Create_a_MadLib = CreateaMadLib.Get__From__Json(Temp_Name)
        Word = Create_a_MadLib.Get__The__Words__From__TheUser()
        Story = Create_a_MadLib.Build__A__Story()
        Create_a_MadLib.Display_A_MadLib_Story()
```

Update:
I replaced Path = "./MadLibGen" with Path = 'C:/MadLibGen' and I get a blank screen when I run it. Is that not correct?

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: It's looking in the current directory for a folder named `MadLibGen`, which does not exist.  The current directory is not necessarily the same directory where the python script is located.  Use this code to see the current directory: `print(os.getcwd())` If I had to guess, I'd say it's using the installation directory of Python itself, or your IDE,  as the current directory.

Comment: By using a absolute path, do you mean using the path.abspath() function, which would look like Path = path.abspath(MadLibGen)?

Comment: I am using MSFT Visual Studio as my IDE. Should I then set the path as the file location for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are on windows, you should be using windows style paths:

```
Path = 'c:\\MadLibGen'
```

Second, you have a recurring issue with wrong capitalization in variable name which should cause your code to crash:

```
if not Path:
    Path = cls.path
```

But `cls` does not have a member `path` it has a memeber `Path` with capital P!

Same here:

```
MadLibGen = os.listdir(CreateaMadLib.path)
```

It should be:

```
MadLibGen = os.listdir(CreateaMadLib.Path)
```

Finally, is the code you posted complete?
It seems to lack the invocation logic - code to create the class and call any methods.

Looks like you are missing something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    madlib = CreateMadLib()
    # call methods
```

Once you add this, you will get more error message such as for this method:

```
def Display_A_MadLib_Story(self):
    print(Story)
```

Which should be:

```
def Display_A_MadLib_Story(self):
    print(self.Story)
```

And probable needs to have some logic to check that `self.Story` is not `None`.